# Is findKey Appropriate for this issue [ Lodash ]

Tags: lodash

So I have these two objects:

```
const objectOne = {
  name: obj,
  sample: obj,
  somethingElse: obj
}

const objectTwo = {
  name: obj,
  a: obj,
  sample: obj
};
```

What I want to do is: search object two for the key in object one. and return the found value. so for example:

**search object two** for `objectOne.name` and get back `{name: obj}` I started with:

```
import findKey from 'lodash/fp/findKey';

export const findValue = (obj1, obj2) => {
  return findKey(obj2, (o) => {
    // What do I do here to get what I want?
  });
}
```

**Can some one point me in the right direction?**

Comment: so let's consider `objectOne.name` is `"ABC"`, so you want to get the key present in `objectTwo` holding the value `"ABC"` and want an output object `{thatKey: "ABC"}` ?